# Hide a text when the container slides

Tags: overflow, hidden, ellipsis

Why is my text not in
"Text overflow: ellipsis"?
I want my text to be directly in ellipsis and the excess text to be hidden when the containers slide.
You can find my code attached.
Thank you for help.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gLtraxh/12/

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;  
    }
.description{ overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.description2{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.price{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    transition: 1s;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: 1s;
    right: 0;
}
.wrapper:hover .price {
    transition: 1s;
    right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <h4 class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h4>
   <p class="description2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae nulla
   </p>
   <span class="price"></span>
   <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jusai, can you also include your css code in your post so that it will be easier for us to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `position: absolute` in this case since it will make the `<div>` **no longer** takes up any space. You can position them with `float` for example:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;  
}

.description
{
  white-space: nowrap; /*I am guessing you want this*/
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.description2
{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.price
{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    transition: 1s;
}

.slide {
    float: right;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: 1s;
    width: 100px;
}

.wrapper:hover .price {
    transition: 1s;
    right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="slide"></div>
   <span class="price"></span>
   <h4 class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h4>
   <p class="description2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae nulla nihil fugit debitis assumenda reiciendis ab velit cupiditate blanditiis perspiciatis hic itaque reprehenderit, enim officia iusto, sint quod modi architecto!
   </p>
</div>
```

Flexbox solution:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;  
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.description-wrapper {
  min-width: 0;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.description
{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.description2
{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.price
{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    transition: 1s;
}

.slide {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: 1s;
    width: 100px;
}

.wrapper:hover .price {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="description-wrapper">
     <h4 class="description">Lorem ipsum</h4>
     <p class="description2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-wrapper">
     <span class="price">sd</span>
     <div class="slide"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, and out of curiosity, is there any other way to get a similar result without float?

Comment: @Jysai Yes, anything used for positioning except `position: absolute`, for example flexbox.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how to do this with flexbox? can you show me please

Comment: @Jysai I added a flexbox solution.

Comment: @Jysai Glad that it helps! If this has solved your problem, you can consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i noticed when i collapse the text the code is not working as expected. Items are no longer at the end of the wrapper.
As you can see in the code below.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;  
}

.description-wrapper {
  min-width: 0;
}

.description
{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.description2
{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.price
{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    transition: 1s;
}

.slide {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: 1s;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="description-wrapper">
     <h4 class="description">Lorem ipsuctetur</h4>
     <p class="description2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</p>
   </div>
   <span class="price">33$</span>
   <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, could you explain what you have changed so I can follow up on this?

Comment: I only reduced the text
in
<h4 class = "description">

&

<p class = "description2">

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer in my flexbox solution. It should be fixed already.